# 12V Battery and RPi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

Just had a quick question that I'm sure is very easy to solve but I just want to make sure before I purchase anything.

I'm working on a project, and I have a 12v battery. I want to power a raspberry pi in this project, but don't want to buy a separate 5V battery.

Here's the battery on amazon: [https://www.amazon.com/26-SEALED-VOLT-DEEP-RECHARGEABLE/dp/B007GCDDOA/ref=sr_1_1?s=industrial&ie=UTF8&qid=1502323193&sr=1-1&keywords=12v+25ah+battery](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007GCDDOA)

I'm assuming I would need a resistor, but I'm not sure which one.

Also, would the 12V battery be too much for a breadboard to handle? Would it melt? I can solder if I need to but would like to use a breadboard for testing.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

That battery is probably overkill, but could be used.

**DO NOT** even try using a resistor. **This will destroy the Pi.**

You need a 5V regulator; I suggest a Switch Mode power module. There are readily available inexpensive modules which take a higher voltage, and produce a well regulated 5V.

See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations) for more info.

Comment: Do you think this would work: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1385?gclid=Cj0KCQjwoZTNBRCWARIsAOMZHmGqzYMDco4J2QdciJgo3bmL7_6oGPpx6ROyUhnYvkbkiRR75rBUgMkaAgZYEALw_wcB

Comment: @flakeyjake yes that would work

Comment: @flakeyjake I use that specific UBEC from Adafruit and have no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

What else are you doing?  If you are driving motors with that battery, you will want a motor driver board to deliver the current to the motors in a controlled way. If that is the case many motor driver boards (eg RedBoard, or Thunderborg or ... there are many others) all provide regulated 5v power to the pi as well as whatever the battery has to the motors.